# Rails alert fires after every view is loaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I understand Asset Pipeline and its purpose. However, the alert in the file `mailers.js` fires after every page is ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#search_mailer").focus();
  console.log( "page is loaded!" );
});
```

A couple of questions:

1. Am I supposed to isolate the `document(ready)` code so it does not fire when all pages are loaded?
2. If I have more that one view with `document.ready` code, does it run it more than once?

Thanks!

Comment: You could add this to `assets.rb` and add `javascript_include_tag` to the views that should use this code (Though I'm not sure that is the "Rails" way).

Answer (score 2):

The `$(document).ready();` should be the "root" function in your file(s) (i.e. there is no code surrounding it). Every time you load a page, every `$(document).ready()` in any included file will fire. What I do to isolate code to a controller and/or action is add a few classes to the `body` tag:

```
<body class="<%=params[:controller].gsub('/', '-')%> <%=params[:action]%>">
```

So you know what controller and action the page belongs to. And with JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  if($('body.user').length > 0) #Example controller name
  {
    #Put controller specific code here
    if($('body.new, body.edit').length > 0) #Example action names
    {
      #Put action specific code here
    }
  }
});
```